# Integration of a matrix over a hypersphere

Tags: matrices, integration

Can anybody please help me on this one please?

$\int_{B({\bf x}_0;R)} \frac{1}{2} ({\bf x} - {\bf x_0})({\bf x} - {\bf x_0})^{T} d{\bf x}$

Here, $B({\bf x}_0;R)$ is a hypersphere(ball?) with radius $R$ with center $\bf x_0$.

Comment: are you sure it's $(x-x_0)(x-x_0)^t$ and notthe other way around??

Comment: I'm pretty sure, but I might be doing something wrong.

The problem was originally 

$\int_{B({\bf x}_0; R)} \frac{1}{2} ({\bf x} - {\bf x}_0)^{T} M ({\bf x} - {\bf x}_0) d{\bf x}$

where $M$ is some matrix.

I took the $M$ out of the integral by making the following transition( ${\bf x}^{T} M {\bf x} = {\rm tr} \ M {\bf x} {\bf x}^T$), but then got my self stuck.  I'm not sure if I was really supposed to do that.

Comment: I am assuming you mean row vectors so $(X- X_{0})(X-X_{0})^{T} = ||(X-X_{0})||^{2}$. Then change to spherical co-ordinates (after translating $X_{0} = 0$ you will get $\int_{B(0; R)} r^{2} dv$. That is standard.

Comment: >DBS

I could see that $({\bf x} - {\bf x}_0)^T ({\bf x} - {\bf x}_0)$ would equal $|| ({\bf x} - {\bf x}_0) ||^2$ as you pointed out, but wouldn't $({\bf x} - {\bf x}_0) ({\bf x} - {\bf x}_0)^T$ become a matrix?

Comment: @Kensuke is $M$ definite positive? in that case what they are asking is the $M$-volume of the ball which should be simpler than that, do you have any extra information about the matrix??

Comment: @JohnC

This is actually the second derivative term in the Taylor series, so it is $\nabla^2 p({\bf x}_0)$ and $p$ is a probability density function.  Would that mean that it is positive definite? Sorry for my lack of knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $\mathbf{x}$ is a column vector, $B(\mathbf{x}_0;R)$ denotes the $n$-ball centered at $\mathbf{x}_0$ with radius $R$ and you are calculating a Riemann integral. Then
$$
\int_{B(\mathbf{x}_0;R)} \frac12 (\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_0)(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_0)^{T} d\mathbf{x}
=\int_{B(0;R)} \frac12 \mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}^T d\mathbf{x}.
$$
Each off-diagonal entry of $\mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}^T$ is of the form $x_ix_j$. For fixed $i$, this is an odd function in $x_j$ and hence its integral over $B(0;R)$ is zero. Therefore, only integrals of the diagonal entries remain. Since the volume of the unit $n$-ball is $\pi^{n/2}/\Gamma(\frac n2+1)$, we get
\begin{align*}
v(n,R):=\int_{B(0;R)} \frac12x_i^2d\mathbf{x}
&= \frac{\pi^{(n-1)/2}}{\Gamma(\frac {n-1}2+1)}
\int_{-R}^R \frac12 x_i^2\left(R^2-x_i^2\right)^{(n-1)/2}dx_i\\
&= \frac{\pi^{(n-1)/2}R^{n+2}}{\Gamma(\frac {n-1}2+1)}
\int_0^1 u^2\left(1-u^2\right)^{(n-1)/2}du\quad(x_i=Ru).
\end{align*}
Hence the required integral is $v(n,R)I_n$.

If $\mathbf{x}$ is a row vector, $\int_{B(0;R)} \frac{1}{2} \mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}^T d\mathbf{x}=\sum_{i=1}^n\int_{B(0;R)} \frac12 x_i^2 d\mathbf{x}$. So, the result is $nv(n,R)$ instead.

Comment: $$\int_0^1 u^2(1-u^2)^{(n-1)/2}du=\frac{B( 3/2, n/2+1/2)}{2}=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}\Gamma(n/2+1/2)}{4\Gamma(n/2+2)}$$, etc., $\Gamma(1/2)=\sqrt{\pi}$.

Comment: @vesszabo Hmm, I would prefer leaving some steps for the OP to complete, but thanks for your work anyway.

Comment: I agree with you, this is the reason of "etc.". (There is a chance that OP never met Beta function.)(+1)

Comment: Thank you very much.  May I ask how you got from $\int_{B(0; R)} \frac{1}{2} x_i^2 d{\bf x}$ to the one on the right?

I do not quite understand why you multiplied the "volume" and not the "surface area", and why $(R^2 - x_i^2)$ is there.

Thank you very much.

Comment: @Kensuke Yes, I did multiply $dx_i$ by the volume of an $(n-1)$-ball because I assume that $B(\mathbf{x}_0,R)$ means an $n$-ball instead of an $(n-1)$-sphere (you wrote in your question "*hypersphere(ball?)*", so I guessed you were not sure whether $B(\mathbf{x}_0,R)$ is a ball or a spherical surface). If by $B(\mathbf{x}_0,R)$ you meant an $(n-1)$ sphere in $\mathbb{R}^n$, the integral is obviously $0$ because the sphere has Lebesgue measure zero. If you use other measures, please specify.